# Who is swaminarayana?

Tags: vishnu

What is the story behind Swaminarayana ? There are many temples known as Akshardham in delhi and gujarat. They worship mainly Swaminarayana. What is the story behind them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaminarayan

Comment: Write summary here as answer

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29836029#29836029